# How to fix constraints for allocation optimisation in PuLP python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

**Background:**

I am trying to allocate customers Ci to financial advisers Pj. Each customer has a policy value xi. I'm assuming that the number of customers (n) allocated to each adviser is the same, and that the same customer cannot be assigned to multiple advisers. Therefore each partner will have an allocation of policy values like so:

P1=[x1,x2,x3] , P2=[x4,x5,x6], P3=[x7,x8,x9]

I am trying to find the optimal allocation to minimise dispersion in fund value between the advisers. I am defining dispersion as  the difference between the adviser with the highest fund value (z_max) and the lowest fund value (z_min).

The formulation for this problem is therefore: 
[image: equations]

where yij=1 if we allocate customer Ci to adviser Pj, 0 otherwise

The first constraint says that zmax has to be greater than or equal to each policy value; since the objective function encourages smaller values of zmax, this means that zmax will equal the largest policy value. Similarly, the second constraint sets zmin equal to the smallest policy value. The third constraint says that each customer must be assigned to exactly one adviser. The fourth says that each adviser must have n customers assigned to him/her. Credit: @LarrySnyder610

**Problem:**

When implementing this problem in PulP, I expect 1740 (n x p) customers to be allocated across the 173 advisers based on constraint 3 and 4. However 72036 and no optimal allocation is obtained.

```py
import random 
import pandas as pd
import pulp 


=============================================================================
# SAMPLE DATA 
=============================================================================

n = 10 # number of customers for each financial adviser
c = 414 #number of customers 
p = 174 #number of financial adviser
policy_values = random.sample(range(1, 1000000), c)


set_I = range(c)
set_J = range(p)
set_N = range(n)
x = {i: policy_values[i] for i in set_I} #customer policy values
y = {(i,j): random.randint(0, 1) for i in set_I for j in set_J} # allocation dummies 


model = pulp.LpProblem("Allocation Model", pulp.LpMinimize)

# =============================================================================
# DECISION VARIABLES
# =============================================================================

y_vars  = {(i,j): pulp.LpVariable(cat=pulp.LpBinary, name="y_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
z_max = pulp.LpVariable("Max Policy Value", 0)
z_min = pulp.LpVariable("Min Policy Value", 0)

# =============================================================================
# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
# =============================================================================

model += z_max - z_min

# =============================================================================
# CONSTRAINTS
# =============================================================================
model += {j: pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I) for j in set_J} <= z_max # constraint 1
model += {j: pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I) for j in set_J} >= z_min # constraint 2
model += {i: pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] for j in set_J) for i in set_I} == 1 # constraint 3
model += {j: pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] for i in set_I) for j in set_J} == n #constraint 4

# =============================================================================
# SOLVE MODEL
# =============================================================================

model.solve()
print('Optimised model status: '+str(pulp.LpStatus[model.status]))

count=0
for v in model.variables():
    if v.varValue == 1.0:
        count+=1
        #print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print(count)
#>>> 72036 # expecting 1740

print('Optimal difference between highest and lowest summed policy_value: ' + str(pulp.value(model.objective)))
```

Do I need to make changes to the objective function/constraints to implement the above equations?

EDIT: Below snippet to try and implement @Erwin Kalvelagen's suggested changes. Still has extremely long durations for higher values of n,p and c:

```py
y_sum = {}

# =============================================================================
# DECISION VARIABLES
# =============================================================================

model = pulp.LpProblem("Allocation Model", pulp.LpMinimize)

y_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('y_vars',((i,j) for i in set_I for j in set_J), lowBound=0, upBound = 1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
z_max = pulp.LpVariable("Max Policy Value")
z_min = pulp.LpVariable("Min Policy Value")
for j in set_J:
    y_sum[j] = pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I])

# =============================================================================
# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
# =============================================================================

model += z_max - z_min

# =============================================================================
# CONSTRAINTS
# =============================================================================

for j in set_J:
    model += pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] for i in set_I]) == n 
    model += y_sum[j] <= z_max
    model += y_sum[j] >= z_min 


for i in set_I:
    model += pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] for j in set_J]) == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. Debug by `print(model)`
2. Start with a small data set
3. The constraints are not correctly formulated. It should be something like

   ```
   for j in set_J:
       model += 1.0e-6 * pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I) <= z_max # constraint 1
       model += 1.0e-6 * pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I) >= z_min # constraint 2
       model += pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] for i in set_I) == n #constraint 4

   for i in set_I:
       model += pulp.lpSum(y_vars[i,j] for j in set_J) == 1 # constraint 3
   ```

   4. The model will be infeasible if `n*p <> c`
   5. Detail: we should probably rewrite constraints 1 and 2. Repeating long summations will create a large number of nonzero elements.

Comment: On (5), how would you recommend rewriting the constraints using pulp? You're right, the model takes ages to solve even using a small data set (n=2,p=10,c=20)

Comment: Never duplicate expressions with a large number of nonzero elements. LP/MIP solvers prefer models that are large and sparse above small and dense. So introduce a new variable `ysum[j] = sum(i, y_vars[i,j]*x[i])`, and use `z_min <= ysum[j] <= z_max`. See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2010/04/l1-portfolio-formulation.html) for another example of this.

Comment: Note that a good MIP solver should have no problem with this. I could solve versions with p=100,c=1000 (so 100k binary variables) in about 10 minutes to global, proven optimality.

Comment: Would you mind adding your code to your answer? I've tried implementing the additional variable/replacing the constraint as per your comment above but keep getting a status of: `Unbounded`. Apologies, must be going wrong somewhere

Comment: I think I know what you did wrong. Pulp requires `z_min <= ysum[j] <= z_max` to be written as 2 sets of inequalities. Again, you could have debugged this yourself by following hints 1 and 2.

Comment: have edited my answer to show my updated changes. Works a charm for low volumes and printing the model does show the constraints how I would expect (larger and more sparse). However run times are still very very very long for bigger volumes. Are there any further changes are need to make to the model set up?

Comment: I have created the additional variables y_sum for each adviser j (saved in a dict on first line) and adapted the constraint as you mentioned. This finds the optimal solution (tested on n=2,p=2). You mentioned above that you have a solution that is able to solve larger versions in approx 10 minutes. Would you be able to share this code? I understand if you wish not to share your solution, in which case thanks for your help to this point

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use that format to add constraints. Try this format instead:

```
for j in set_J:
    model += pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I]) <= z_max
```

etc.

Note also the `[...]` inside the `lpSum(...)`.

Finally, I don't think you can declare variables the way you did. I usually use `LpVariable.dicts()`, as in:

```
y_vars = pulp.lpVariable.dicts('y_vars', set_I, 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes to the setup you suggested. However I can't test to see if this is a fix due to the solve run times. As @Erwin Kalvelagen mentioned, I think is due to constraints 1/2. Do you know how they could/should be re-written in pulp?

Comment: I think @Erwin Kalvelagen's comment about "rewriting" these constraints is not about PuLP syntax -- he's saying that the constraints *as formulated algebraically* might lead to weak formulations (weak LP bounds) and therefore result in a model that takes a long time to solve. I think he is right, but unfortunately I don't think there is an easy fix for that -- these minimax-type problems are notorious for exactly this sort of issue.

Comment: One thing you could try is to replace the RHSs of those constraints with constants -- e.g., guess, in advance, the min and max value of the portfolios, and impose those as bounds. Then delete the $z^\max$ and $z^\min$ variables from the model and get rid of the objective function -- just make it a feasibility problem. This is a different model from the original one, and I don't know if you like it as your "final" model, but it might be worth checking the run times for that model.

Comment: I'll check this out. When you say "get rid of the objective function" I'm assuming you also mean replace it with something else?

Comment: You can `minimize 0`. You can also replace it with something else. `PuLP` might also allow you to simply have no objective function; I'm not sure.