# How to make linear programming optimization faster

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

I am trying to allocate customers Ci to financial advisers Pj. Each customer has a policy value xi. I'm assuming that the number of customers (n) allocated to each adviser is the same, and that the same customer cannot be assigned to multiple advisers. Therefore each partner will have an allocation of policy values like so:

P1=[x1,x2,x3] , P2=[x4,x5,x6], P3=[x7,x8,x9]

I am trying to find the optimal allocation to minimise dispersion in fund value between the advisers. I am defining dispersion as the difference between the adviser with the highest fund value (z_max) and the lowest fund value (z_min).

The formulation for this problem is therefore:
[image: formulation]

where yij=1 if we allocate customer Ci to adviser Pj, 0 otherwise

The first constraint says that zmax has to be greater than or equal to each policy value; since the objective function encourages smaller values of zmax, this means that zmax will equal the largest policy value. Similarly, the second constraint sets zmin equal to the smallest policy value. The third constraint says that each customer must be assigned to exactly one adviser. The fourth says that each adviser must have n customers assigned to him/her.

I have a working solution using the optimization package: `PuLP` that finds the optimal allocation.

```py
import random 
import pulp 
import time


# DATA

n = 5 # number of customers for each financial adviser
c = 25 # number of customers 
p = 5 # number of financial adviser
policy_values = random.sample(range(1, 1000000), c) # random generated policy values 

# INDEXES

set_I = range(c)
set_J = range(p)
set_N = range(n)
x = {i: policy_values[i] for i in set_I} #customer policy values
y = {(i,j): random.randint(0, 1) for i in set_I for j in set_J} # allocation dummies 

# DECISION VARIABLES

model = pulp.LpProblem("Allocation Model", pulp.LpMinimize)

y_sum = {}
y_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('y_vars',((i,j) for i in set_I for j in set_J), lowBound=0, upBound = 1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
z_max = pulp.LpVariable("Max Policy Value")
z_min = pulp.LpVariable("Min Policy Value")
for j in set_J:
    y_sum[j] = pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] * x[i] for i in set_I])

# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION

model += z_max - z_min

# CONSTRAINTS

for j in set_J:
    model += pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] for i in set_I]) == n 
    model += y_sum[j] <= z_max
    model += y_sum[j] >= z_min 


for i in set_I:
    model += pulp.lpSum([y_vars[i,j] for j in set_J]) == 1 

# SOLVE MODEL

start = time.clock() 
model.solve()
print('Optimised model status: '+str(pulp.LpStatus[model.status]))
print('Time elapsed: '+str(time.clock() - start))
```

Note that I have implemented constraints 1 and 2 slightly differently by including an additional variable y_sum to prevent duplicating an expression with a large number of nonzero elements

**The problem**

The issue is that for larger values of n,p and c the model takes far too long to optimise. Is it possible to make any changes to how I've implemented the objective function/constraints to make the solution faster?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367696/3453768) about replacing $z^\max$ and $z^\min$ with constants?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I couldn't get PuLP to minimize on 0 - which I accept may be a limitation of the package rather than your solution

Comment: Then just introduce a new variable `w`; minimize `w` and use `w >= 0`.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Try a using a commercial solver like Gurobi with pulp. You should get a substantial decrease in solve time.

Also check your computers memory, if any solver runs out of memory and starts paging to disk the solve time will be very long.

Answer (score 0):

You should monitor the time needed for each part of the program (model declaration and solving)

If the solving is too long, you can use a different solver as suggested above (here is some clue how to do it : https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html).

If the model declaration is too long, you may have to optimise your code (try to use the pulp enabled fuctions as `pulp.lpSum` rather than python `sum` for example). You can also fidn some tricks here https://groups.google.com/g/pulp-or-discuss/c/p1N2fkVtYyM and here https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/efficient.ipynb